# What is the transmitting API for master in I2C for EFR32?

Tags: i2c

I could not find in the [EFR32 I2C API](https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/5.4/efr32fg14/group-EFR32FG14P-I2C-BitFields) the functions related to sending data to, or communicating with, a slave in general, as shown in the diagram below. Is there something like this?

[image]

Comment: What is the slave device you're transmitting to?  You'll probably find the information you're looking for there.  Otherwise general protocol information is in the I2C spec.

Comment: The link i brought is the I2C API spec.
there is no transmit command.
https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/5.4/efr32fg14/group-EFR32FG14P-I2C-BitFields

Comment: You're looking at the register bit-field definitions. [Here](https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/5.4/efr32fg14/group-I2C) is the API description.

Comment: Hello, i have looked there the closesnt thing i saw is 
 I2C_Transfer (I2C_TypeDef *i2c) which ontinue an initiated I2C transfer (single master mode only).
But there is no function which resembles the I2C structure of
send address of the slave then send the co mmand to the slave.Is there such function there?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you linked version 5.4.  The current version is 5.9, I would refer to that instead.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Now you need to provide that function different flags to tell the MCU exactly what you want it to do.  What is your slave device?

Comment: My slave device is si7021 sensor. I have posted my diagram in the first post.What is the strategy? i know that TXC rises when we send the while buffer for example and we can call a function when it rises.

Comment: can i have an example regarding "telling" things to this function using flags? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the source code (si7021.c) I posted.  You will see how the flags are used with the `seq` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Silicon Labs provides a simplified driver to communicate with your specific humidity and temperature sensor (Si7021).  The driver is in the board support package.

Here is the driver documentation:

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8c.html

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8h.html

Source Code:

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8c_source.html

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/si7021_8h_source.html

The source code appears pretty straight forward.

Comment: Hello,How do i build a project from the web site you shown. I am new  to this,i am femiliar with github example website where i can download a whole folder and import a whole project from the folder.How to assemble a project from the website page you shown?
Thanks
https://github.com/SiliconLabs/peripheral_examples/tree/master/series1/i2c/i2c

Comment: I've never actually used that MCU from Silicon Labs.  I assume you have a development board from Silicon Labs did it come with any documentation or software examples?

Comment: No examples what so ever,abosutly NONE,
I dont know how to assemble the commands in the API driver you showed.I dont know what to do,I just want a basic examples.
Is there some thing i could use to build this example?